# Finding the intersection in two lists of tuples regardless of tuple order

Tags: python, list, tuples, intersection

I have two lists of tuples

```
listA = [('1','2'),('3','4'),('5','6')]
listB = [('2','1'),('7','8')]
```

I want to find the intersection of them even if the order of the tuple in the second list is different.

So, for the example above:

```
intersection = [('1','2')]
```

the intersection should return the tuple above though it is not in the same order in listB

How can I do that in python the most efficient way? because each of my list has around 2000 tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> set(map(frozenset, listA)) & set(map(frozenset, listB))
{frozenset({'1', '2'})}
```

Note that this assumes uniqueness in the tuples (i.e. there's no tuple `('1', '1')`).

Comment: how to get this return a list of tuples of format [('1','2')]

Comment: You could do `[tuple(element) for element in result]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can sort each element in lists, convert them to tuples, then convert lists to sets and check sets intersection:

```
set(
    [
        tuple(sorted(elem))
        for elem in listA
    ]
) & set(
    [
        tuple(sorted(elem))
        for elem in listB
    ]
)
```

returns:

`{('1', '2')}`

Answer (score 2):

1. Try to sort the tuples in list.
2. Convert lists to sets.
3. Print the intersection of sets.

   ```
   listA = [('1','2'),('3','4'),('5','6')]
   listB = [('2','1'),('7','8')]
   for i, j in enumerate(listA):
       listA[i] = tuple(sorted(j))
   for i, j in enumerate(listB):
       listB[i] = tuple(sorted(j))
   listA = set(listA)
   listB = set(listB)
   print(list(listA.intersection(listB)))
   ```

Output:

```
[('1', '2')]
```